# Pycharm OutOfMemoryError

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

After installing PyCharm, I am getting this error

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm (and all Jetbrains IDE's) use Java, and its memory usage can be  configured with [JVM Options](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties)

If you are trying to use IntelliJ/PyCharm on limited memory environments (like a Raspberry Pi), you'll need to reduce the memory size (`-Xmx` flag). Otherwise, use a lighter-weight option like VSCode or Jupyter for Python development